# JSP include throw file not found exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I'm using JSP tag to create a template for my site, however, when I try to move my files into another folder, the jsp include tag throw file not found exception.

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/components/layout/header.jsp`

[image]

This is the content of my layout tag
[image]

The first include tag works well but the include tag for header is broken but the path to it seem fine in the exception above.

Thank for reading.

EDIT:

This is how I use the layout tag
[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `../user/components/layout/header.jsp`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer nope, still the same error :'(

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual path to that is?

Comment: At first I put every jsp files in the Web Pages folder and the jsp include tag for head works fine but then I move all jsp files into a subfolder user (the image above) and the error occurred with the first jsp include tag in the layout.tag file. I fixed it by adding ../ but I can do that with the include tag for header.jsp.

Comment: If I add the user/ to the include tag for header like this:
`<jsp:include page="user/components/layout/header.jsp"></jsp:include>` The error becomes: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/user/components/layout/header.jsp
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, turn out when I re-deploy the project, the code seem to be working again -_- . Anyway, thank you guys so much for spending your time with this question.